# When is a good time to use tables?

Tags: html, html-table, standards

I'm building a small social networking website for a university project and this question is purely a cosmetic thing.

Basically, my tutors are really anti-table and are very strict on the fact you may only use them for tabular data, but I am not really sure what is and what isn't considered tabular data. Would an inbox be considered tabular data? I would quite like to use zebra striping in displaying this and as the data is rendered dynamically in a loop it would be a pain to do this with CSS and divs.

When, if ever, would you use tables?

Comment: As a guide "it would be a pain ... with CSS and divs" is a very poor reason to use a table.

Comment: @IainGalloway - I understand that and am willing to suffer through if an inbox is not actually tabular data, but I'm having a hard time with the semantics of it all and can't really discern whether or not an inbox would be tabular data?

Comment: @KerrekSB I get the impression you didn't read my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree you want to use tables when display tabular data so yes an inbox would be an ok time to use tables.  The big concern I think people have with tables is when you use them for layout of the entire site.  Use div's to layout the site and then tables to display tabular data.

Answer (score 3):

Tables are for grids of **logically-associated** data.

Zebra-striping works the same way - add a class name to every other row.

Comment: is having the columns "sender" "subject" "date/time" not logically associated data? I would have no qualms zebra striping with css if it wasn't for the fact the data was coming from a database with a foreach loop.

Comment: Have the loop add a class name on every second iteration.

Comment: yes I would say those are logically associated.  I think the issues people have is when tables are used to layout a page and then complain because they can't get things to line up appropriately.

Comment: @Diodeus It seems like a lot of code to add if I don't need to, do you not think that an inbox would be logically associated data?

Comment: I never claimed they weren't. Striping is can be done in a few lines of code.